# opensuse 13 enterprise crontab won't execute jar file

Tags: linux, shell, opensuse

i have some issue on running shell script to execute jar file in opensuse,

Below is the way set for crontab:

```
contrab -e 
5 */1 * * * /path to shellscript/run.sh
```

Below is the way shell script contain:

```
#! bin/sh
cd /project/jar/
/usr/local/jdk1.8/bin/java -jar /project/jar/pike.jar
```

From the file above already given chmod 777 permission.
Is there anything wrong about the setting? if i execute the shell script it run directly, from tracing systemlog follow by /var/log/message, from here able to check crontab is execute with the job id display. From the java log file it doesn't show anything.

Please help on this. thank you.

Comment: `#bin/sh` is invalid -  should be `#!/bin/sh`. `/path to shellscript/run.sh` - does the path contain spaces? `*/1` - divided by 1? Does that mean every hour? It's the same as just `*`, no?

Comment: @KamilCuk path to shellscript not contain any space, */1 execute hourly

Comment: @Comsphere: Clarify: After you fixed the buggy `#!` line, is the problem that the script does not run at all, or that it runs but produces error messages? BTW, I would not give a file which is supposed to run by cron the permissions 777. This is  literally inviting trouble.

Comment: Add logs in your crontab entry, so you know what is going on.  `>/tmp/out.txt 2>out2.txt` for example.

Comment: @user1934428 yes i have try this out

Comment: @Nic3500 try on running single shell script to echo string into a text files it works by setting up in crontab

Comment: And what do the logs on the real script say?